# Detect if Windows CE PDA is connected to Network

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-ce, opennetcf

In my Windows CE application, I need to know if the PDA is connected (before calling web services).

I tried to use OpenNetCF ConnectionManager class but it always indicates a "Disconnected" status.

```
ConnectionManager connectionManager = new ConnectionManager();
var wifi = ConnectionManager.ConnectionDetailItems.Where(x => x.ConnectionType == ConnectionType.NIC).FirstOrDefault();
connectionManager.Connect(wifi.SourceNetwork, true, ConnectionMode.Synchronous);
```

When I do that, connexionManager status is always equal to "Disconnected" whereas the static member "ConnectionManager.ConnectionDetailItems" contains an item with my network info.

So I'd like to know how I can use ConnectionManager to determine if the Pad is connected.

PS: my network has no access to the Internet

Comment: Just put a ping (in code) to the IIS server that holds the web service you want to use. If the ping is OK, you are connected. If the ping fails, a call to the web service will fail too.